# mapserver raster legend ticks

Tags: raster, legend, mapserver

I am serving rasters through mapserver and the maps look fine. I have managed to include a raser legend by setting:

```
 LEGEND
    KEYSIZE 200 12
    LABEL
      TYPE BITMAP
      SIZE MEDIUM
      COLOR 0 0 89
    END
    STATUS EMBED
  END
```

My 'Class' inside my 'Layer' looks like:

```
CLASS
        NAME "my_legend_name"
        STYLE
            RANGEITEM "Band 1"
            COLORRANGE 255 255 178  189 0 38
            DATARANGE 1700 2000
        END
      END
```

This gives me a nice legend. However, it missing ticks and values. So, there are no clues to what values the different colors represent. How can ticks be added to the embed legend? Is it even possible? I have also called the legend with GetLegendGraphic through openlayers wmsSource.getLegendUrl but without finding a way to set ticks. I would think this would be possible?

Comment: Did you give names for your classes https://mapserver.org/input/raster.html? Ticks are probably not supported.

Comment: I have updatet my post with name for my class.

Comment: Does the name "my_legend_name" appear in the legend? If it does, you can edit the name to show the datarange "1700-2000".

Comment: Yes it does. That would be more useful I guess. Feels like a dirty hack and I do not get ticks at 1800 and 1900. But I will use that for now, until I (or someone) find a better solution. Thanks!

Comment: That's how the legend labels work in MapServer, also for vector layer classes. You may want to ask from the mapserver-users mailing list if someone knows how to add ticks to the legend. It it is possible then I guess that it requires html legend template https://mapserver.org/output/html_legend.html#html-legend.